# MySQL error 1215: Can not add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I am trying to forward engineer my new schema onto my db server, but I can't figure out why I am getting this error. I've tried to search for the answer here, but nothing I've tried worked.

This is the error I get when I am trying to forward engineer my new schema onto my DB server:
[image]

Comment: post the structure for others tables involved

Answer (score 0):

Few things might cause an issue:

1) Check what data types are `studentnummer` column in `student` table and `vakID` in `vakklas` - Are they `INT` and `VARCHAR(45)`?
2) Check for typing errors - are tables and columns you're referencing named same way as in this CREATE statement?
3) Check if `student` and `vakklas` already have some rows that violate `NOT NULL` condition - is there a record with NULL value in referenced columns?
4) Are you using InnoDB for all tables?
5) Are you sure charset is the same on all tables? This is important especially because you're using VARCHAR as foreign key. Try adding `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` after `ENGINE = InnoDB` on all queries for table creating - it might solve the problem

Comment: 1. Yes I've used INT and VARCHAR, is that not correct? 4. I think so but i'm not sure. I don't know how to fix the last point you mentioned...What can I do?

Comment: That is ok if it matches. Also, check if VARCHAR is 45 and charset used on these values.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me how to use charset on these values. I have exactly no idea how to do that.